# Is there more to consider than the R-value when installing stucco in the Southwest?

Tags: insulation, energy-efficiency, stucco

I live in the Southwest and notice 90% of the homes in my area are stucco. Since I'm considering wrapping the house in an additional layer of insulation, then new siding, I am considering stucco.

Many articles argued that stucco is amazing in the Southwest's climate, where it can get quite cold in the winter, however, when I searched the R-value, I found it is only R-value of 0.2. Since some 2" installation can provide R11, it doesn't seem logical to pay for high-cost stucco over if its only adding such an infinitesimally small amount of extra R-value. If it is only R0.2, why is it so great in the Southwest?

Is stucco really great for the Southwest as so many on-line article suggest, even though it give such low value?

Comment: you are correct, stucco is no used for it R-value, but for its durability to withstand  high prolonged sun exposure without cracking or fading. The actual thermal insulation goes under the stucco.

Comment: I believe there's also an air-sealing benefit; no gaps in the stucco like there are in siding.

Answer (score 1):

Clapboards are very popular in New England as siding material. Nobody relies on them for insulation. (Well, not for the last 100 years or so, but that's a different story.)

Vinyl siding is a very popular siding material all around the country despite the fact that it adds zero insulation.

Stucco is popular in the southwest despite its minimal insulating capacity.

Nobody puts siding on for its insulating value. Its purpose is to protect everything inside the siding from the majority of the weather (things like house wrap protect against the rest). The stuff inside happens to include the insulation.

If the siding adds any insulating value at all, then that's just a bonus.

Answer (score 1):

You might be conflating stucco with EIFS (which is basically synthetic stucco over foam) - Exterior Insulation and Finishing System. THAT has as much R-value as you put in it.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exterior_insulation_finishing_system